# Generate 4 columns of data such that each row sum to 100

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I wanted to randomly generate 4 columns of positive numbers such that the numbers for each row sum to 100, how do I do this in Excel or some other program that you can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You question has a lot of nifty and hairy statistics in it if you require all the numbers to be identically distributed. If that is not required, just put in columns A, B and C a `=RAND()*33` and in D a `=100-A1-B1-C1`. If you look at the distribution of the data, the columns A, B and C are identically distributed (mean of 16,5 and a range of <0,33>), but column C has an mean of 50 and a range of <0, 100>.

I need to dive [deeper into the statistics of sums of uniformly distributed data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) to find an answer that fits the uniform distribution requirement (if that is a requirement at all).

Answer (score 1):

This is for a **single row** from **E1** thru **H1**

In **A1** thru **D1** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

In **E1** enter:

```
=100*A1/SUM($A1:$D1)
```

Copy **E1** and paste from **F1** thru **H1**

For example:

[image: x]

.

Now that you have a single row, just copy downwards.

Comment: Elegant solution. Better than mine. +1.